# Players.iiNethanC.PlayerGui.Shop.Core:65: attempt to index nil with 'Clone' -

Tags: lua, roblox

```lua
local  handle = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("ToolModels"):FindFirstChild(availableTools[i][1].."Handle"):Clone()
```

pls help i can't figure out what is wrong

everything i've tried doesn't fix my problem

Comment: There's no real way for us to help you based on the code you've shared. What is `availableTools[i][1]`? Because `game.ReplicatedStorage.ToolModels` doesn't have a child named that + "Handle"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `:FindFirstChild(availableTools[i][1].."Handle"):Clone()` doesn't exist, but `ToolModels` does

Answer (score -1):

You did not add the parent. This means that it will not work and wont go to a specific place. You can use a variable and then your path with the :Clone ad then put variable.Parent = parent here

Comment: The error is saying that it failed to find an object to clone. So there's no object to set the parent of yet.